# cell.selectionStyle = .none stopped working

Tags: swift, uitableview

trying to make a cell not selectable if the hours = 0.  it was working before I added the prepare for segue to push data to the next scene.   the alpha and background color still work but cell.selectionStyle = .none does not now.  can't figure out why

---

```
 override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {


    let cell = UITableViewCell()
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "E-MM-dd-yyyy"

    let newDate = dateFormatter.string(from: twoDWeeksArray[indexPath.section][indexPath.row])
    getWeeklyHours(newDate: newDate)
    let cellLabel = "Week of " + (newDate) + "                        " + String(hours) + " Hrs"

    if hours == 0 {

        cell.backgroundColor = .lightGray
        cell.textLabel?.alpha = 0.50
        cell.selectionStyle = .none

    }

    cell.textLabel?.text = cellLabel


    hours = 0.00
    return cell
 }
```

Comment: `cell.textLabel?.text = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone` I think you can also do `cell.isUserInteractionEnabled = false`

Comment: Awesome! Thank you so much.  Cell.isUserInteractionEnabled = False worked!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `cell.isUserInteractionEnabled = false` in swift basically any view can have its interaction enabled or disabled. A cell is nothing more than another content view and as such it can be disabled.

Answer (score 0):

The `selectionStyle` property does nothing to prevent a cell from being selected. It describes how the cell should look when it is selected. A value of `.none` says that the cell shouldn't look any different than when it's not selected. However, the user can still select the cell.

If you don't want a cell to be selected, then implement the `UITableViewDelegate.tableView(_:willSelectRowAt:)` delegate method and return `nil` for rows that should not be selectable.

Disabling user interaction might also solve this for you, but I don't recommend that because it is not idiomatic iOS and might have unexpected side effects.

Comment: What do you mean that it is not idiomatic?